# Best way to use Scala MongoClient in Play 2.0

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.0, casbah

I have just started using Play 2.0 with Scala and Casbah for connecting to MongoDB. I have been able to connect to my MongoDB instance but what I am looking for is a way to be able to access the MongoClient from all my model classes.

Is there any DependencyInjection way to inject mongoClient in all Scala models ? or

Should I have one Scala object which initialises the MongoClient and use that object to refer to MongoClient in all my models ? or

Is there a more better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

As MongoClient uses a connection pool internally, its optimal to only have a single instance for your application and that single object can then be used by all your models.

Also, you could look at [Salat](https://github.com/novus/salat) which might do what you require or give you an idea on how best to implement your own models.